# Java: How can I type cast to a "Runtime" Class?

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting

Code snippet :

```
private List<Animals> createAnimanlsIstance(Class cls) {
   Class typeCastedObject  =   (cls)getObjectBySomeCalculation();

}
```

Lets Say, I pass the Class as Dog.class at run Time and I want to type cast to Dog class Object.
How can I achieve this, My above code is just a sample, Of what I want.

It's not like :

```
 if( obj instanceOf ClassA)
 {
   Object = (ClassA)  obj;
  }
```

I will be passing an instance of Class as parameter, ex : Dog.class,Cat.class etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might try generics:

```
private <T> List<Animals> createAnimalsInstance(Class<T> cls)
{
    T typeCastedObject = (T) getObjectBySomeCalculation();

}
```

Then you can simply use this method as usual:

```
List<Animals> animals = createAnimalsInstance(Dog.class);
```

---

FYI: If you want to do `instanceof` you can use [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
if (obj instanceOf AClass)
```

is equivalent with

```
if (AClass.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()))
```

Comment: Let me try all these, Thanks all for suggestion and that too, a quick one :)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use generics:

```
private <T> List<Animal> createAnimalsInstances(Class<T> clazz) {
    T castedObject = (T) getObjectBySomeCalculation();    
}
```

If the casted objects are intended to be added into a `List<Animal>` (i.e. are extending `Animal`), then you'll need:

```
private <T extends Animal> List<Animal> createAnimalsInstances(Class<T> clazz) {
    T castedObject = (T) getObjectBySomeCalculation();    
}
```

Comment: Thannks, but all the passed classed are not related, and also After type casting I have to call one api(common to All class).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Class typeCastedObject = cls.cast(getObjectBySomeCalculation());
```